# Copying file to remoteserver Powershell

Tags: powershell

Hi how can we copy multiple files to multiple servers at the same time instead of going one by one?
Here i have list of servers in serverslist.txt……
Files folder named as “Softwares” where we have list of files to copy.
Can we able to do this using powershell?

Answer (score -1):

This should do what you need:

```
Get-Content "path to server list" | Foreach-Object { Copy-Item -Path "path to software folder" -dest (join-path $_ "Destination folder name")}
```

Comment: This won't "copy multiple files to multiple servers at the same time instead of going one by one".

Comment: I think to do that, You may want to use something other than powershell